# Need Box shadow for mat-row Angular

Tags: angular, mat-table

I want to bring box shadow while hovering in . Using CSS `box-shadow` does not work well with bottom border except last one.

Somehow it seems the lower row border is blocking the display of shadow and thus is not visible. Is `mat-elevation` can be used here?
tried it but could not make it work.

HTML:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" >

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
          [class.box-shadddo]="row.name == hoveredName" 
          (mouseover)="mouseOver(row)"
          (mouseout)="mouseLeft()"></tr>
</table>
```

TS:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  hoveredName;

   mouseOver(row) {
    if(this.hoveredName !== row.name)
      this.hoveredName = row.name;
  }

  mouseLeft(){
    this.hoveredName = undefined;
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}

.box-shadddo {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px grey;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Found a pure css way to achieve this with the transform: scale css property.

```css
.mat-row:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

In this rule definition the scale doesn't change the size but brings the row to the front layer.

Also sharing this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rows-with-boxshadow) demo

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. Made it work in my real code.

Comment: Maybe you could consider accepting this as the answer =D
Cheers

Comment: Yes that was the answer i meant. Thank you again . :)

Comment: `transform: scale(1);` works like a charm for my table row box shadow problem.  Thank you!!!